# Issue returning https url when returning response from a docker container

Tags: apache, docker, lamp, docker-machine

I am using docker which has an apache container and a lamp container. Lamp container contains the application code and Apache container has virtual host config info which is as follows.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName example.com
     Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ProxyPreserveHost on
     ProxyPass / http://172.18.0.25/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://172.18.0.25/
     SSLProxyEngine on
     SSLEngine on
     SSLProxyVerify none
     SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
     SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
     SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
     SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/STAR_example_com.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/example_wildcard_private.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/STAR_example_com.ca-bundle
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
     RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</VirtualHost>
```

Issue: When i am making a request to https://example.com then in response the apache container is returning response from http://example.com instead of https://example.com.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Lamp is receiving an http request from Apache, so you have to tell Lamp that the initial request, from the client, was through https.

Try adding this in the https virtual host definition:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

With this header, Lamp should understand that the client did the request through https, so it will answer from https as well.

So, your virtual host definition should look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName example.com
     Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ProxyPreserveHost on
     ProxyPass / http://172.18.0.25/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://172.18.0.25/
     SSLProxyEngine on
     SSLEngine on
     SSLProxyVerify none
     SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
     SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
     SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
     SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/STAR_example_com.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/example_wildcard_private.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/STAR_example_com.ca-bundle
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
     RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
     RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
</VirtualHost>
```